# syntax error on production server where running bin/python setup.py test-q

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid

When I attempt to do the following on a production server:

```
    $ sudo -u vretnet ../bin/python setup.py test -q
```

It will show the following error, how should I fix this?
Or could it be that my development.ini went wrong?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 34, in <module>
        paster_plugins=['pyramid'],
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/vretnet/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 138, in run self.with_project_on_sys_path(self.run_tests)
    File "/home/vretnet/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 118, in with_project_on_sys_path 
        func()
    File "/home/vretnet/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 164, in run_tests
        testLoader = cks
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/unittest/main.py", line 123, in __init__
        self.parseArgs(argv)
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/unittest/main.py", line 191, in parseArgs
        self.createTests()
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/unittest/main.py", line 198, in createTests
        self.module)
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/unittest/loader.py", line 132, in loadTestsFromNames
        suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/unittest/loader.py", line 132, in <listcomp>
        suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
    File "/opt/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
        module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
    File "/home/vretnet/env/ECommerce/ecommerce/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pyramid.config import Configurator
    File "/home/vretnet/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid-1.4-py3.2.egg/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from webob.exc import WSGIHTTPException as WebobWSGIHTTPException
    File "/home/vretnet/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/WebOb-1.2.3-py3.2.egg/webob/exc.py", line 1115, in <module>
        from paste import httpexceptions
    File "/home/vretnet/env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Paste-1.7.5.1-py3.2.egg/paste/httpexceptions.py", line 634
        except HTTPException, exc:
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Python 3, you should write `as`:

```
except HTTPException as exc:
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've also managed to fix others like             raise got_exc[0], got_exc[1], got_exc[2]. Thanks for giving me a starting point to use as a reference.

Comment: How did you fix the got_exc[0], got_exc[1], got_exc[2]?

Answer (score 0):

This took me a couple of days to figure out ><. But make sure you install the correct mod_wsgi version. You can install that uses python2 or one that uses python3.

If you install the python3 wsgi mod and use virtualenv2 to build your python environment you will get packages that aren't written for python3.

Comment: That isn't strictly true. You can when using any recent version of virtualenv, even if installed for Python 2, and supply the --python option referring to Python 3 binary and it will create a virtual environment for the Python 3 installation. This is actually required right now if want to use virtual environments with Python 3 under mod_wsgi as pyvenv doesn't work for embedded systems like mod_wsgi as they didn't implement pyvenv support for that correctly in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

you just use this patch bellow.

```
$ 2to3 example.py
```

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/2to3.html#to3-python-2-3

translate code from python2 to python3 automatically and recursively.